# Strange Axis Behavior

Tags: d3.js, topojson

I have a color coded map of China, and it was working fine until I added a color scale and an axis to the right of the map. You may view it here:

https://bl.ocks.org/diggetybo/4c42aafc20c21e416585c9e37079eda2

The problem is, a province went missing after I added the axis. By missing, I mean it is not visible anymore. I'm not sure if it's actually still there but has a fill of none, or for some reason the path was not drawn altogether. It is a very large province too, in the northwest of China. For those hard core in geography, the name of the province is Xinjiang.

At first I was convinced it was user error on my part, but after much toiling I slowly started to suspect it could be a bug of some kind. I did manage to narrow it down to which line: line 69, or the `.call(axis);` line in the snippet below:

```
var axisNodes = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (margins.left+865) + ',' + (margins.top) + ')')
    .call(axis);
styleAxisNodes(axisNodes);
```

I literally commented out every other line, and only the `.call(axis);` line makes the province disappear. You can try for yourself, just comment out line 69 and the province will reappear.

**My question:** What does an axis have to do with a totally different section of my code, the fill of a json parsed map path? Why did it **only** affect that province? And what can I do to avoid this?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do this inside your `d3.json` function:

```
svg.selectAll("path")
```

You are in fact selecting an already existing path, which is the axis' path, and binding data to it.

Because of that, your "enter" selection will have one element less.

**Solution**: select something that doesn't exist:

```
svg.selectAll("foo")
```

Here is your updated bl.ocks: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/387781c5bccb0339141b519c098f5605

PS: another solution is calling the axis **after** painting the map.

PPS: *"Why did it only affect that province?"* That province is the first one in the data.